# Can anyone explain the inner product within a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

I saw this formula on a machine learning paper, but just couldnt get my head around it. Can you anyone help me understand it?

Suppose $H$ is a RKHS, K a kernel function, and $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3,\ ... \}$ and $\{\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3 \ ...\}$ are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions satisfying $\int K(x,y)\psi_j(y) = \lambda_j\psi_j(y)$.

For any f and g from H, we can write $f=\Sigma\alpha_i\psi_i$ and  $g=\Sigma\beta_i\psi_i$. Then why is the inner product $<f,g>=\Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha_i\beta_i/\lambda_i$?

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Integral_operators_and_Mercer.27s_theorem

Comment: i believe the inner product is defined in this way because it leads to the reproducing property of RKHS